# Swift Avplayer inside tableview cell still playing when dismissing changing controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I configure an avPlayer inside my tableview cell:

```
func createPlayer(url: URL) {
    self.playerCell = AVPlayer(url: url)
    self.videoContainerView.playerLayer.bounds = self.videoContainerView.bounds
    self.videoContainerView.playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    self.videoContainerView.playerLayer.player = playerCell
     playerCell?.play()
}
```

than call this function whenever the user click a button

```
@IBAction func playBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let videoUrlString = post?.mediaUrl, let url = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
        createPlayer(url: url)
    }
    playBtn.isHidden = true
}
```

In my tableview controller i can stop the player whenever the cell is not displayed anymore like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as? VideoCell else {return}
    if cell.playerCell != nil {
        if (cell.playerCell?.rate != 0) && (cell.playerCell?.error == nil) {
            cell.playerCell?.pause()
            cell.playerCell = nil
            cell.playBtn.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if from the tableview controller i switch to another controller or dismiss the controller the video is still playing.
How can i stop the Player?

I need the indexpath to identify the player so i cannot call the function inside viewWillDisappear.

Hope somebody could help, I've tried to fix this for 3 days...

Thank you!
----------------------UPDATE
I've tried to do so:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
 guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? VideoCell else {return}
    if cell.playerCell != nil {
        if (cell.playerCell?.rate != 0) && (cell.playerCell?.error == nil) {
            cell.playerCell?.pause()
            cell.playerCell = nil
            cell.playBtn.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not works...

Comment: Implement `viewWillDisappear`? I don't understand why you can't use this. You know what cells you've got, so just quickly look at all of them. — You should probably worry also about _why_ the player keeps playing; do you have a memory leak on your view controller?

Comment: @matt i wrote it... in viewWillDisappear i cannot get the indexPath of the cell... so cannot get the player is actually playing...

Comment: No, I don't get that. You know what cells you've got, so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: each cell might have a player... i tried to implement the pause method inside the viewWillDisappear.. nothing happens.. because i cannot use tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath).. whithout the indexPath it will not remove the player

Comment: If each cell might have a player, then stop every cell. Your objections make no sense to me. I don't see why this is hard.

Comment: that's what i thought it would work.... i've updated the question

Comment: i did it... got confused because is being days i was trying... added like so now: for visibleCell in tableView.visibleCells {
            if let cell = visibleCell as? VideoCell { and then inside remove the player.. and it works... thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement `viewWillDisappear` to call `visibleCells` and cycle through them looking for a VideoCell. Each time you find one, tell it to stop playing just as in the code you already have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this it's same like viewWillDisappear

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? YouTableViewCell else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         cell.videoPlayer.player?.pause()
         cell.videoPlayer.player = nil
         cell.videoPlayer.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

An even more elegant solution would be to override func prepareForReuse() and pause the player there. Removing it might be not the best thing as from cell to cell you can replace the current item in the AVPlayer instance like
avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: videoPlayerItem)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
    for i in indexPath! {
        
        let cell : myCustomCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: i) as! MyCustomCell
        
        cell.mmPlayerLayer.player?.pause()
    
    }
  }
}
```